# problem binding arrow keys with xbindkeys

Tags: xbindkeys, xev, xte

I'm trying to bind ctrl+win+p to act as an "UP" arrow key. I'm going to use xbindkeys so first of all I start `xbindkeys -k` to see the code for this combination. It gives me such an output:

```
set@set001:~$ xbindkeys -k
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x54 + c:33
    Control+Mod2+Mod4 + p
```

then I'm using this simple macro in `~/.xbindkeysrc`

```
"xte 'key Up'"
    Control+Mod2+Mod4 + p
```

but nothing happens when I'm restarting xbindkeys with `killall -s1 xbindkeys ; xbindkeys` and type ctrl+win+p

all other bindings in `~/.xbindkeysrc` working just fine

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

finally I was able to rebind everything I want and even more.

put this in `~/.config/xkb/my`:

```
xkb_keymap {
  xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
  xkb_types     { include "complete" };
  xkb_compat    { include "complete" };
  xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };

  xkb_symbols "my" {
    include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)"
    include "capslock(swapescape)"
    include "group(alt_shift_toggle)"

    key <TLDE> { [ grave, asciitilde ] };

    key <LALT> { [ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
    modifier_map Mod5 { ISO_Level3_Shift };

    key <AD09> { [o, O, Up, Up] };
    key <AC09> { [l, L, Down, Down] };
    key <AC08> { [k, K, Left, Left] };
    key <AC10> { [colon, semicolon, Right, Right] };
    key <AC10> { [colon, semicolon, Right, Right] };
    key <SPCE> { [space, BackSpace, BackSpace] };
    key <BKSP> { [BackSpace, BackSpace] };
    key <AD08> { [i, I, Delete] };
    key <AB07> { [m, M, Prior] };
    key <AB08> { [ comma,   less, Next] };
  };
};
```

then restart it with `xkbcomp ~/.config/xkb/my $DISPLAY`

Comment: so you give up xbindkeys?

Comment: yeah. Can't find to make it work like I need.